# Finish the sequence (hopefully not too easy)

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

This is a number sequence. Can you guess the right answer? GOOD LUCK :)

0,1,2,4,14,21....

Can you guess the next 4 numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next 4 numbers are:

> 22, 24, 31, 32

Because:

> they are numbers containing the letter 'o'

OEIS:

> A008519

Answer (score 5):

The next four numbers are

> 22, 24, 31, 32

Because

> When written in English, these are the numbers that contain the letter 'o'.

Comment: oops, sniped by you... but pls also check the oeis ;)

Answer (score 1):

The next four numbers are

> 22,24,31,32

Reason

> _0_contains o(zero)
> 1 contains o (one)
> 2 contains o(two) so on  etc

This puzzle is about

> finding presence of o in in English form thus the answer is 22 24 31 32 contains o

Comment: There are already two existing answers that are duplicates. Usually we dont post duplicates as they will usually get downvoted and deleted. We express agreement or approval in the way of upvoting others' answers. Happy Puzzling ;)